# ABCPDF error on trying to create pdftable

Tags: abcpdf

I'm trying to create a pdf table using ABC PDF. But, couldn't able to create PDFTable while declaring PDFTable its shows error.

```
        Doc theDoc = new Doc();
        // set up document
        theDoc.FontSize = 16;
        theDoc.Rect.Inset(20, 20);

        PDFTable theTable = new PDFTable(theDoc, 5);
        theTable.CellPadding = 5;
        theTable.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        theText = theText.Trim();
        theText = theText.Replace("\r\n", "\r");
        string[] theRows = theText.Split(new char[] { '\r' });

        for (int i = 0; i < theRows.Length; i++)
        {
            theTable.NextRow();
            string[] theCols = theRows[i].Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            theCols[0] = "<stylerun hpos=0>" + theCols[0] + "</stylerun>";
            //theTable.AddTextStyled(theCols);
            if ((i % 2) == 1)
                theTable.FillRow("220 220 220", i);
        }
        theTable.Frame();

        theDoc.Flatten();
        theDoc.Save("docaddgrid.pdf");
        theDoc.Clear();
```

Comment: What version of ABCpdf are you using and what is the error?